# HTC One M8 GPE unable to run Android 5.0 or 5.1

Tags: htc, htc-one-m8

Attempts to install Android 5.0 and 5.1 ROMs from various sources result in a device that doesn't boot properly. Among side effects:

- it doesn't display the boot animation (just a static Android logo)
- takes forever to boot
- WiFi cannot be turned on

This is due to incorrect firmware, but the device is **S-ON** and installing any [available RUU .zips](http://www.graffixnyc.com/m8.php) fails with a signature check error.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to install the **firmware-only** RUUs rather than the full RUUs. While the full RUUs are tampered with and therefore won't pass signature checks on non-S-OFF devices, the firmware RUUs provided on http://www.graffixnyc.com/m8.php are authentic, and will install on S-ON devices.

Make sure you update in stages:

1. Install firmware 3.11.1700.5 (for Android 5.0.1) — look for file with MD5 **a3e2bd4b51c0ceff46e52f521e9454be** on the GraffixNYC page
2. Install firmware 4.04.1700.4 (for Android 5.1) — look for file with MD5 **6ac5701060b4e15adb0cef7f13eddccd** on the GraffixNYC page

If your device is unlocked (not S-OFF, just unlocked), you might need to temporarily relock it before you can install RUUs:

1. `fastboot oem lock`

Installing RUUs is done with:

1. `fastboot oem rebootRUU`
2. `fastboot flash zip firmware.zip`